# how to set an environment to kickoff github actions workflow

Tags: github, azure-devops, github-actions, devops, cicd

Having trouble with resolving this error on github actions:

```
Run if [ "" == "dev" ]; then
  if [ "" == "dev" ]; then
    echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  elif [ "" == "tst" ]; then
    echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=main" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  else
    echo "Unknown environment: "
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "Deploying from branch $DEPLOY_BRANCH"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    ENV: 
    APP_NAME: cache-loader
    APP_SERVICE_PLAN: 
Unknown environment: 
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It's landing on an `Unknown Environment`, but I have set the `tst` and `dev` environment in the `Settings` of github repository.

Here's is the workflow yaml file:

```
on:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      data-exchange-hl7-branch:
        description: 'Branch from data-exchange-hl7 that you want to deploy to the development environment'
        default: 'develop'
        required: true
        type: string
      environment:
        type: choice
        description: "allow choice of environment to deploy"
        options:
          - dev
          - tst
        required: true

env:
  ENV: ${{ vars.ENV }}
  APP_NAME: cache-loader
  APP_SERVICE_PLAN:  ${{ vars.APP_SERVICE_PLAN }}

jobs:
  setup-build-env:
    runs-on:  [self-hosted, hl7]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
          cp settings.xml /tmp/settings.xml
      - name: choose a branch
        run: |
          if [ "${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}" == "dev" ]; then
            echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=${{ inputs.data-exchange-hl7-branch }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          elif [ "${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}" == "tst" ]; then
            echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=main" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "Unknown environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}"
            exit 1
          fi
          echo "Deploying from branch $DEPLOY_BRANCH"
      - name: Checkout company/data-exchange-hl7
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository:  company/data-exchange-hl7
          ref: ${{ env.DEPLOY_BRANCH }}
```

Is this the correct conditioning:

`if [ "${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}" == "dev" ]; then`?

Comment: Are you running the workflow based on a pull_request event?

Comment: yes, i'm running the workflow based on  a pull_request event

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do this

**Option 1: Using [jobs if](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif)**

```
jobs:
  get-env-using-ga:
    runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: is dev branch?
        if: inputs.environment == 'dev'
        run: echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=topic-branch" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: is test branch?
        if: inputs.environment == 'test'
        run: echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=main" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      
      - name: Print DEPLOY_BRANCH 
        run: echo "Deploying from branch ${{ env.DEPLOY_BRANCH }}"
```

**Option 2: Using bash**

```
jobs:
  get-env-using-bash:
    runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set DEPLOY_BRANCH
        run: |
          if [[ ${{ inputs.environment }} == 'dev' ]]; then
            echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=topic-branch" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          elif [[ ${{ inputs.environment }} == 'test' ]]; then
            echo "DEPLOY_BRANCH=main" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi
        shell: bash
      
      - name: Print DEPLOY_BRANCH 
        run: echo "Deploying from branch ${{ env.DEPLOY_BRANCH }}"
```

Comment: What is `topic-branch`? Names for these branches are up to the user...so how do you set it without knowing how a user will name it?

Comment: you can make them come from `workflow_dispatch` inputs or use `github.ref` to pick the branch that triggered the workflow